# Eclipse - Java keypress event

Tags: java, eclipse, events, keypress

im trying to make a block of code run once you hit a key like you press "space" key then it will run the block of code I cant find a way to do this I have googled for a little over 5 hours (not just looking for this) and found everything else I need but cant find something on this so if anyone knows how to do this please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind I found a fix for this im just going to add a gui and button to do this anyway I was just going to add a gui soon